# Thunar command line options

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

Are there any command line options that can launch Thunar with different display options for that instance?

I sometimes want Thunar to use the directory tree sidebar view instead of the usual shortcuts view. Is there an option I could use so I can create a launcher for each view?

`man thunar` and `thunar --help` weren't helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Thunar & command line**

Like you, I could not find any direct command to open a new window in either treeview or shortcuts (left) pane. I doubt if they are available.

There is however a workaround, but I don't know if you want it to be "pure", or if your goal is mainly to make it functional via command line, so that you can make a starter. If the last is the case, there is a pretty straightforward solution in `xdotool`.

**Using xdotool to create a command**

The side pane view in Thunar is set by key combinations. You can simulate these key combinations with xdotool in a command. xdotool is not installed by default, so you have to install it first:

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

To generate a working command which you can use in a starter, you need to know that the key combinations to set the tree/shortcut view are:

```
ctrl+e
ctrl+b
```

The command to open a new Thunar window in tree view:

```
thunar; xdotool key ctrl+b; xdotool key ctrl+e
```

[image]

or shortcut view:

```
thunar; xdotool key ctrl+e; xdotool key ctrl+b
```

[image]

To make a double xdotool command seems odd, but that is necessary to prevent Thunar from cycling through the options, and hide the side pane.

if you want the window to open in a specific directory; add the directory to the command:

```
thunar /path; xdotool key ctrl+e; xdotool key ctrl+b
```

**Other Thunar options**

No need to say that you can use other options in Thunar in a similar way, just look at the key combination(s) after the menu options.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and for introducing me to xdotool. Looks like an interesting tool.

Comment: I think it is! for situations you have to make a workaround ;)

Answer (score 5):

xfce save thunar setting in

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml
```

For example, to change an attribute of the window, as the width of the sidebar, type:

```
xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /last-separator-position --set 400
```

you can create a shell script that changes the values ​​first and then run thunar.
ie, create a file `thunar.sh` as:

```
#!/bin/bash

xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /last-side-pane --set ThunarTreePane
xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /last-separator-position --set 200
thunar &
```

and run it by typing:

```
sh thunar.sh
```

With a little modification you can select the type of left pane by passing the argument "tree" to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PANE="ThunarShortcutsPane"
if [ $# -eq 1 ] && [ "$1" = "tree" ]; then
   PANE="ThunarTreePane"
fi
xfconf-query --channel thunar --property /last-side-pane --set "$PANE"
thunar &
```

so, for open thunar with treeview pane, type:

```
sh thunar.sh tree
```

or, for shortcut pane:

```
sh thunar.sh
```

refer to [xfce thunar doc page](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/start) for more setting and help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using this method would require two scripts, one for each side pane setting. I appreciate the info, I can probably modify this to my needs.

Comment: I made ​​a small change to my answer by adding a simple script to toggle between the two views.