# What is the File Operation Progress popup?

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I frequently get a popup box saying File Operation Progress when using Thunar to copy files.

Another small box shows on the upper right side.

When I right click it, a box opens saying "File Operation Progress.'

What is that and how can I stop that?

[image]

4/16/23

I did a complete purge of Thunar and a re-install.

The popup box continues to stay open after the file copying has completed.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi UbuntuMate 20.04

Comment: @ Archisman Panigrahi  How do I do a complete purge of Thunar including all configuration files. I will then do a re-install of Thunar.

Comment: @fixit7, (1) check list of notification services available `grep -r org.freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/` (2) verify which one is active using `d-feet` tool and look which service takes `org.freedesktop.Notifications` D-Bus address. (3) Thunar is part of XFCE, I'm expecting either `org.freedesktop.mate.Notifications.service` (`mate-notification-daemon`) or `org.xfce.xfce4-notifyd.Notifications.service` (`xfce4-notifyd`) (4) Thunar has only one config file in the package `/etc/xdg/Thunar/uca.xml` , rest of the config either through `xfconf` or in `~/.config/` folder...

Comment: ... To reset user config delete `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/thunar.xml` or use `xfconf-query` to reset "thunar" setting channel, here some posts as reference: https://askubuntu.com/q/446458/26246 , https://askubuntu.com/q/1060116/26246 , https://askubuntu.com/a/224037/26246 .

Comment: @ user.dz andy@7 ~> grep -r org.freedesktop.Notifications /usr/share/dbus-1/services/
/usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.mate.Notifications.service:Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications

Answer (score 0):

The File Operation progress shows when there is a file being copied/transferred from one directory to another.

The second box that shows on the upper right is the **Notification** of the action ongoing. To disable the notification, either turn on DND mode, or under notification settings block that application from sending notifications.

Comment: Thanks. I could use some details on what you said. Have you actually tested what you suggested?
Nishant Majumdar